# mean.io angularjs bootstrap modal 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack, mean.io

Hi I have the following code in my controller

```
$scope.openModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/packages/system/public/views/nuggetModal.html',
        controller: 'NuggetModalController'
    });
}
```

But I get a 404 whenever I try to run the code via ng-click. I have tried lots of variations of the templateUrl, I can't fathom the problem.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the templateUrl is:

```
templateUrl: 'system/views/nuggetModal.html'
```

Despite that not being the physical path